# Image flickers and page scrolls to top when http request is made in Angular - Video inside

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, angular-material

Video: https://vimeo.com/341988489

I have an alerts-page which contains multiple alerts. Each alert has a boolean "isRead" that indicates whether the alert is read or not. An orange envelope indicates that an alert is not read. When this orange envelope is clicked, it turns grey and an http-request is sent to the server to update this boolean-value from false to true.

A few problems occur in the application when this happens:
1. The image avatar that is shown in the alert "flickers" and the page is scrolled to the top.
2. The UI freezes for a few seconds.

This seems to happen whenever an http-request is made to the server in the alerts-page-component. Both when the alert-components "envelope" is clicked and toggleIsRead is called, but also when "mark all as read" is clicked as shown in the video.

I have no idea what is causing this issue. But I have shown the network-tab in the develoer tools if this can give any clues.

In alerts-page.component.ts I am fetching alerts for the current user from the server, and initializing an Observable called messages in alert-messages.service.ts. This is then used to populate alertsCreatedToday and alertsCreatedAWeekAgo. These observables are then set to alertsCreatedToday$ and alertsCreatedAWeekAgo$.

Each alert is then populated with data from these Observables. A mat-card is displaying the information for each alert.

When the envelope on an alert is clicked to toggle the boolean "IsRead" - this boolean is using the optimistic update approach to first change the boolean on the "alertRecipient-model" and then calls the server via http to update the database. This is done in users-endpoint.service.ts via alerts.service.ts.

I don't know if all this information is needed. Perhaps there are a simple solution to the problem, but I figured I might as well supply as much information as possible.

I don't know how to find a solution to this problem, because I have not got any clue regarding what may be causing it.

alerts-page.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'alerts-page',
    templateUrl: './alerts-page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./alerts-page.component.scss'],
})
export class AlertsPageComponent implements OnInit {

    alertMessages$: Observable<AlertMessage[]>;
    alertsCreatedToday$: Observable<Alert[]>;
    alertsCreatedAWeekAgo$: Observable<Alert[]>

    alertMessagesFromServer: AlertMessage[];
    alertMessagesFromClient: AlertMessage[];
    alertRecipients: AlertRecipient[];
    currentUser: User = new User();
    groups: Group[] = [];
    users: User[] = [];
    newMessages: AlertMessage[];

    alertMessages: AlertMessage[];

    constructor(private alertMessagesService: AlertMessagesService,
        private alertsService: AlertsService,
        private notificationMessagesService: NotificationMessagesService,
        private dialog: MatDialog,
        private usersService: UsersService,
        private groupService: GroupsService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadData();
        this.initializeObservables();
    }

    private initializeObservables() {
        this.alertMessages$ = this.alertMessagesService.messages;
        this.alertsCreatedToday$ = this.alertMessagesService.alertsCreatedToday;
        this.alertsCreatedAWeekAgo$ = this.alertMessagesService.alertsCreatedAWeekAgo;
    }


    private loadData() {

        this.currentUser = this.usersService.currentUser;

        forkJoin(
            this.alertsService.getAlertMessagesForUser(this.currentUser.id),
            this.groupService.getGroups(),
            this.usersService.getUsers()
        ).subscribe(
            result => this.onDataLoadSuccessful(result[0], result[1], result[2]),
            error => this.onDataLoadFailed(error)
        );
    }

    private onDataLoadSuccessful(alertMessagesFromServer: AlertMessage[], groups: Group[], users: User[]) {
        this.alertMessagesFromServer = alertMessagesFromServer;
        this.groups = groups;
        this.users = users;

        this.alertMessagesService.messages.subscribe(
            (alertMessagesFromClient: AlertMessage[]) => this.alertMessagesFromClient = alertMessagesFromClient
        );

        if (this.newMessagesFromServer()) {
            this.newMessages = _.differenceBy(this.alertMessagesFromServer, this.alertMessagesFromClient, 'id');
            this.newMessages.map((message: AlertMessage) => this.alertMessagesService.addMessage(message));
        }


    }

    private onDataLoadFailed(error: any): void {

        this.notificationMessagesService.showStickyMessage('Load Error', `Unable to retrieve alerts from the server.\r\nErrors: "${Utilities.getHttpResponseMessage(error)}"`,
            MessageSeverity.error, error);
    }

    private newMessagesFromServer(): boolean {
        if (this.alertMessagesFromClient == null && this.alertMessagesFromServer != null) {
            return true;
        } else if (this.alertMessagesFromServer.length > this.alertMessagesFromClient.length) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    markAllAsRead() {
        this.alertsService.markAlertsAsRead(this.currentUser.id).subscribe(
            (alertRecipients: AlertRecipient[]) => {

                alertRecipients.map((alertRecipient: AlertRecipient) =>
                    this.alertMessagesService.markRead(alertRecipient));
            }

        );
    }

}
```

alerts-page.component.html

```
<button (click)="markAllAsRead()">Mark all as read</button>

    <h2>Today</h2>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let alert of alertsCreatedToday$ | async">
            <alert [alertRecipient]="alert.alertRecipient"[alertMessage]="alert.alertMessage">
            </alert>
        </ng-container>


    <h2>Last Week</h2>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let alert of alertsCreatedAWeekAgo$ | async">
            <alert [alertRecipient]="alert.alertRecipient"[alertMessage]="alert.alertMessage">
            </alert>
        </ng-container>
```

alert.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'alert',
    templateUrl: './alert.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./alert.component.scss'],
})
export class AlertComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() alertRecipient: AlertRecipient;
    @Input() alertMessage: AlertMessage;
    currentUser: User = new User();

    constructor(private dialog: MatDialog,
        private alertsService: AlertsService,
        private usersService: UsersService,
        private alertMessagesService: AlertMessagesService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.currentUser = this.usersService.currentUser;
    }

    getAvatarForAlert(alertMessage: AlertMessage): string {
        return require('../../../assets/images/Avatars/' + 'default-avatar.png');
    }


    toggleIsRead(alertRecipient: AlertRecipient) {
        this.alertRecipient.isRead = !alertRecipient.isRead;
        this.alertsService.toggleIsRead(alertRecipient)
            .subscribe(alertRecipient => {
                this.alertMessagesService.toggleRead(alertRecipient);
            }, error => {
                this.notificationMessagesService.showStickyMessage('Update Error', `An error occured while attempting to mark the alert-message as read.`, MessageSeverity.error, error);
                this.alertRecipient.isRead = !alertRecipient.isRead;
            });
    }
}
```

alert.component.html

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
        <div [ngSwitch]="alertRecipient.isRead" (click)="toggleIsRead(alertRecipient)">
            <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase="true">drafts</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase="false">markunread</mat-icon>
        </div>
    </mat-card-header>

    <mat-card-content>
        <div class="avatar-wrapper" fxFlex="25">
            <img [src]="getAvatarForAlert(alertMessage)" alt="User Avatar">
        </div>

            <h3>{{alertMessage.title}}</h3>
            <p>{{alertMessage.body}}</p>
    </mat-card-content>

    <mat-card-actions>
        <button>DELETE</button>
        <button>DETAILS</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

alert-messages.service.ts

```
const initialMessages: AlertMessage[] = [];

interface IMessagesOperation extends Function {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:callable-types
    (messages: AlertMessage[]): AlertMessage[];
}

@Injectable()
export class AlertMessagesService {

    _hubConnection: HubConnection;

    newMessages: Subject<AlertMessage> = new Subject<AlertMessage>();
    messages: Observable<AlertMessage[]>;
    updates: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
    create: Subject<AlertMessage> = new Subject<AlertMessage>();
    markRecipientAsRead: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
    toggleReadForRecipient: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

    alertsCreatedToday: Observable<Alert[]>;
    alertsCreatedAWeekAgo: Observable<Alert[]>;

    constructor() {
        this.initializeStreams();
    }

    initializeStreams() {
        this.messages = this.updates.pipe(
            scan((messages: AlertMessage[],
                operation: IMessagesOperation) => {
                return operation(messages);
            }, initialMessages),
            map((messages: AlertMessage[]) => messages.sort((m1: AlertMessage, m2: AlertMessage) => m1.sentAt > m2.sentAt ? -1 : 1)),
            publishReplay(1),
            refCount()
        );

        this.create.pipe(map(function (message: AlertMessage): IMessagesOperation {
            return (messages: AlertMessage[]) => {
                return messages.concat(message);
            };
        }))
            .subscribe(this.updates);

        this.newMessages
            .subscribe(this.create);


        this.markRecipientAsDeleted.pipe(
            map((recipient: AlertRecipient) => {
                return (messages: AlertMessage[]) => {
                    return messages.map((message: AlertMessage) => {
                        message.recipients.map((alertRecipient: AlertRecipient) => {
                            if (alertRecipient.recipientId === recipient.recipientId
                                && alertRecipient.alertId === recipient.alertId) {
                                alertRecipient.isDeleted = recipient.isDeleted;
                            }
                        });
                        return message;
                    });
                };
            })
        ).subscribe(this.updates);

        this.markRecipientAsRead.pipe(
            map((recipient: AlertRecipient) => {
                return (messages: AlertMessage[]) => {
                    return messages.map((message: AlertMessage) => {
                        message.recipients.map((alertRecipient: AlertRecipient) => {
                            if (alertRecipient.recipientId === recipient.recipientId
                                && alertRecipient.alertId === recipient.alertId) {
                                alertRecipient.isRead = true;
                            }
                        });
                        return message;
                    });
                };
            })
        ).subscribe(this.updates);

        this.toggleReadForRecipient.pipe(
            map((recipient: AlertRecipient) => {
                return (messages: AlertMessage[]) => {
                    return messages.map((message: AlertMessage) => {
                        message.recipients.map((alertRecipient: AlertRecipient) => {
                            if (alertRecipient.recipientId === recipient.recipientId
                                && alertRecipient.alertId === recipient.alertId) {
                                alertRecipient.isRead = recipient.isRead;
                            }
                        });
                        return message;
                    });
                };
            })
        ).subscribe(this.updates);

        this.alertsCreatedToday = this.messages.pipe(
            map((alertMessages: AlertMessage[]) => {
                const alerts: Alert[] = [];
                alertMessages.map((alertMessage: AlertMessage) => {
                    alertMessage.recipients.map((alertRecipient: AlertRecipient) => {
                        if (this.wasCreatedToday(alertMessage)) {
                            const alert = new Alert(alertRecipient, alertMessage);
                            alerts.push(alert);
                        }
                    });
                });
                return alerts;
            })
        );

        this.alertsCreatedAWeekAgo = this.messages.pipe(
            map((alertMessages: AlertMessage[]) => {
                const alerts: Alert[] = [];
                alertMessages.map((alertMessage: AlertMessage) => {
                    alertMessage.recipients.map((alertRecipient: AlertRecipient) => {
                        if (this.wasCreatedBetweenTodayAndAWeekAgo(alertMessage)) {
                            const alert = new Alert(alertRecipient, alertMessage);
                            alerts.push(alert);
                        }
                    });
                });
                return alerts;
            })
        );

    }


    addMessage(message: AlertMessage): void {
        this.newMessages.next(message);
    }


    toggleRead(alertRecipient: AlertRecipient): void {
        this.toggleReadForRecipient.next(alertRecipient);
    }

    markRead(recipient: AlertRecipient): void {
        this.markRecipientAsRead.next(recipient);
    }

    wasCreatedToday(alertMessage: AlertMessage): boolean {
        const today = moment();
        const alertSentAt = moment(alertMessage.sentAt);

        return moment(alertSentAt).isSame(today, 'day');

    }

    wasCreatedBetweenTodayAndAWeekAgo(alertMessage: AlertMessage): boolean {
        const today = moment();
        const alertSentAt = moment(alertMessage.sentAt);
        const oneWeekAgo = moment(moment().subtract(7, 'days'));

        return moment(alertSentAt).isBetween(oneWeekAgo, today, 'day');
    }

}

export const alertMessagesServiceInjectables: Array<any> = [
    AlertMessagesService
];
```

alerts.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AlertsService {

    constructor(private usersEndpoint: UsersEndpoint) { }

    getAlertMessagesForUser(userId: string): Observable<AlertMessage[]> {
        return this.usersEndpoint.getAlertMessagesForUserEndpoint<AlertMessage[]>(userId);
    }

    markAlertsAsRead(userId: string) {
        return this.usersEndpoint.getMarkAlertsAsReadEndpoint<AlertRecipient[]>(userId);
    }

    toggleIsRead(alertRecipient: AlertRecipient) {
        return this.usersEndpoint.getToggleIsReadEndpoint<AlertRecipient>(alertRecipient);
    }

}
```

users-endpoint.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersEndpoint extends EndpointFactory {

    private readonly _usersUrl: string = '/api/users';

    get usersUrl() { return this.configurations.baseUrl + this._usersUrl; }

    constructor(http: HttpClient, configurations: ConfigurationService, injector: Injector) {

        super(http, configurations, injector);
    }

    getAlertMessagesForUserEndpoint<T>(userId: string): Observable<T> {
        const endpointUrl = `${this.usersUrl}/${userId}/alertmessages`;

        return this.http.get<T>(endpointUrl, this.getRequestHeaders()).pipe<T>(
            catchError(error => {
                return this.handleError('Unable to get alert-messages for user with id: ' + userId, error, () => this.getAlertMessagesForUserEndpoint(userId));
            }));
    }

    getMarkAlertsAsReadEndpoint<T>(userId: string): Observable<T> {
        const endpointUrl = `${this.usersUrl}/${userId}/alertmessages/markallread`;

        return this.http.put<T>(endpointUrl, null, this.getRequestHeaders()).pipe<T>(
            catchError(error => {
                return this.handleError('Unable to mark alertmessages as read for user with id: ' + userId, error, () => this.getMarkAlertsAsReadEndpoint(userId));
            }));
    }

    getToggleIsReadEndpoint<T>(alertRecipient: AlertRecipient): Observable<T> {
        const endpointUrl = `${this.usersUrl}/${alertRecipient.recipientId}/alertmessages/${alertRecipient.alertId}/toggleread`;

        return this.http.patch<T>(endpointUrl, JSON.stringify(alertRecipient), this.getRequestHeaders()).pipe<T>(
            catchError(error => {
                return this.handleError('Unable to toggle isRead-status for alert-message to user with id: ' + alertRecipient.recipientId, error, () => this.getToggleIsReadEndpoint(alertRecipient));
            }));
    }

    getMarkAlertRecipientAsDeletedEndpoint<T>(alertRecipient: AlertRecipient): Observable<T> {
        const endpointUrl = `${this.usersUrl}/${alertRecipient.recipientId}/alertmessages/${alertRecipient.alertId}/markdeleted`;

        return this.http.patch<T>(endpointUrl, JSON.stringify(alertRecipient), this.getRequestHeaders()).pipe<T>(
            catchError(error => {
                return this.handleError('Unable to mark alert-message as deleted', error, () => this.getMarkAlertRecipientAsDeletedEndpoint(alertRecipient));
            }));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is happening because your messages are rerendered because of `alertsCreatedToday$` and `alertsCreatedAWeekAgo$` observables are emitting new values every time the `AlertMessagesService.update Subject` emits a new value. Instead of re-rendering, you want to refresh the data on the alert component. For this purpose, you should use `trackBy`. Let's change the code like this -

### Today

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let alert of alertsCreatedToday$ | async; trackBy: trackByFn1">
        <alert [alertRecipient]="alert.alertRecipient"[alertMessage]="alert.alertMessage">
        </alert>
    </ng-container>


<h2>Last Week</h2>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let alert of alertsCreatedAWeekAgo$ | async; trackBy: trackByFn2">
        <alert [alertRecipient]="alert.alertRecipient"[alertMessage]="alert.alertMessage">
        </alert>
    </ng-container>
```

In your `export class AlertsPageComponent` have two functions like this -

```
trackByFn1(item, index) {
  //return the id of your alert
  return item.alertId;
}

trackByFn2(item, index) {
  //return the id of your alert
  return item.alertId;
}
```

Refer - https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5 for more details.

Comment: Wow, thanks alot for the help! This solved all the problems that occured. I hope you have an awesome day - you totally made mine!

Comment: @IsakVidinghoff You are very welcome! Good to know that it solved your issue. Keep questioning and keep learning..:) We all learn this way..:)